# Pass callback to angular component create with route

Tags: angular, angular-component-router

I have a component that is created with a route and this component has an Output EventEmitter. How can I subscribe to this Output if the component was created on routing?

The component is created like this:

```
{ path: 'component-A',
  component: ComponentAComponent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<new-component (event_emitter_variable_name)="custom_function()"></new-component>
```

To know more go to this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular)

---

**Update**

You can create service to can communicate between two components. component 2 will subscribe on a event in the service. component 1 will push to this event in the service. [example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/21/angular-8-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject).

[image]

Comment: The component is created with a route.

Comment: Sorry for not understand your question .I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the activate EventEmitter from the router-outlet

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onRouterActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

$event is your routed Component, then you can listen to an Event. Depending on what you want to achieve, using a Service may be a better choice.